# How to get the .class of a Generics defined entity?

Tags: java, jaxb, nested-generics

So how can I do the following in Java?

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();       
JAXBElement<List<String>> jax = new JAXBElement<List<String>>(new QName("strings"), List<String>.class, strings);
```

The issue specifically occurs at List.class and the error returned is:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- List cannot be resolved to a variable
- String cannot be resolved to a variable
- Syntax error on token ">", void expected after this token
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

The closest approximation to what you want is to use `(Class<List<String>>) List.class`.

This is because there is no `List<String>.class`, because at runtime, `List<String>`, `List<Banana>`, `List<FruitSalad>`, and `List` are all the same in Java.  This is deliberately done for a whole bunch o' reasons, and it's called type erasure.

Comment: "This is deliberately done for efficiency" Source? I'm pretty sure the primary reason for erasure was backwards compatibility.

Comment: Here's a cool blog post from Ola Bini about what problems reified generics would cause in the JVM: http://olabini.com/blog/2010/07/questioning-the-reality-of-generics/