# Call method.invoke(...) passing List<Map<String,Object>> as argument

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to call this method by reflection, but I'm not succeeding.

```
Method method = App.class.getDeclaredMethod("imp" + tipTransa,
                        Connection.class,                       // connection
                        String.class,                           // token
                        String.class,                           // tipTransa
                        String.class,                           // tipOpe
                        String.class,                           // msgGuid
                        List<Map<String,Object>>.getClass());   // this is the problem
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(null, conn, token, tipTransa, tipOpe, msgGuid, data);
```

How can I resolve the `List<Map<String,Object>>.getClass()` problem?

Comment: This kind of question has been answered a couple of times already. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/12009285/521799, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401468/how-to-get-the-class-of-a-generics-defined-entity, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851544/how-do-i-get-class-type-of-generic-list/15851614

Comment: I wish I could mark all as right answer. Thank you guys. Pshemo and Paul Boddington.

Comment: @RodrigoGarcia Since all posted answers are correct feel free to accept one you like the most :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the raw type:

```
List.class
```

I.e.

```
Method method = App.class.getDeclaredMethod("imp" + tipTransa,
                    Connection.class,                       // connection
                    String.class,                           // token
                    String.class,                           // tipTransa
                    String.class,                           // tipOpe
                    String.class,                           // msgGuid
                    List.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

At runtime, there is no difference between a `List<Map<String,Object>>` and a `List<Double>` or a `List` of any other type, because generic type information is erased.

You can just use `List.class`.

Answer (score 2):

Generics don't exist at runtime (or to be more precise they are [erased](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) at compilation time), so there is no need for runtime literal containing generic types.

Instead of

```
List<Map<String,Object>>.getClass()
```

use

```
List.class
```